# Check if a string exists in array

Tags: c++

For a school assignment I need to check whether a string entered by the user is stored in a pre-defined word array.

I want to implement a function to perform the check, that may look like this:

```
bool exists(dict words, char check) { /* how to implement this? */ }
```

But I have no clue whether this will work or how to implement it. Can anyone help?

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct dict {
    string word;
};

int main() {
    dict words[5];
    words[0].word = 'abc';
    words[1].word = 'bcd';
    words[2].word = 'cde';
    words[3].word = 'def';
    words[4].word = 'efg';

    char user_input[100];
    cin.getline(user_input, 100);
    if (...) { // how do I check if the user input is in my word array?
        cout << "found\n";
    }
    else {
        cout << "not found\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: ... and string literals.

Comment: ... and how to ask (in Stack Overflow)

Comment: This might be a school assignment, but if not there are better data structures to store strings, like e.g. plain [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). Then it will also be very easy to find specific "words" using [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find). Right now you can use [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find), but it's a little more complicated.

Comment: yes this is part of my school assignment.

Comment: You might also want to read about [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), as then you don't have to worry about plain `char` arrays and sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `dict` is a structure and `char` is type able to hold single character, so you would rather need to have:

`bool exists(const dict* words, const string& check);`

From this point, I would say, that:

- `const dict*` should be changed to `const vector<dict>&`.
- `std::getline` is able to [read input directly into string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), so no plain char array is needed.

But since it's a school assignment, I suppose, that you have some limitations (and can't use neither `std::vector` nor [std::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find), that would do the job). So:

```
bool exists(const dict* words, size_t count, const std::string& check)
{
    for(size_t n = 0; words && (n < count); ++n)
    {
        if(words[n].word == check)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Example:

```
dict langs[3];

langs[0].word = "C++";
langs[1].word = "Java";
langs[2].word = "Python";

std::string s_1 = "Java";
std::string s_2 = "C++ 11";

printf("exists(%s) : %s\n", s_1.c_str(), exists(langs, 3, s_1) ? "yes" : "no");
printf("exists(%s) : %s\n", s_2.c_str(), exists(langs, 3, s_2) ? "yes" : "no");
```

Output:

```
exists(Java) : yes
exists(C++ 11) : no
```

[Link to sample code](http://ideone.com/kZUlwM).

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer has already pointed out, you should add a size parameter to the function signature in order to be able to iterate the array (especially to know when to stop iteration.). Then a simple loop with a comparison will do the trick.

Note that you shouldn't normally need to use raw arrays in C++, but rather one of the containers from the standard library, e.g., `std::vector`. Also, you should use `std::string` and `std::getline()` for your user input, and you should fix your string literals (use double quotes "..." instead of single quotes '...'). Further, you should avoid `using namespace std;` conciouslessly. Have a look at the links at the end of this post for some further reading on these points.

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

bool exists(std::string const & user_input, 
            std::vector<std::string> const & words)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++)
        if (user_input == words[i])        
            return true;
    return false;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> words(5);
    words[0] = "abc";
    words[1] = "bcd";
    words[2] = "cde";
    words[3] = "def";
    words[4] = "efg";

    std::string user_input;
    std::getline(std::cin, user_input);
    if (exists(user_input, words))
        std::cout << "found\n";
    else
        std::cout << "not found\n";
}
```

Example output:

```
$ g++ test.cc && echo "abc" | ./a.out
found
```

---

The following might be beyond the scope of your school assignment, but maybe this will be helpful for future visitors to this question.

Note that an array (which `std::vector` is) is not the most efficient data structure to perform this sort of task, as you have to iterate the entire array to check every single item (linear complexity).

The C++ standard library also provides the container types `std::set` and `std::unordered_set` (the latter since C++11). Here the search space is organized in a special way (binary search tree: logarithmic complexity, hash table: constant complexity on average) to improve lookup time of the key type (`std::string` in this case).

Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

typedef std::set<std::string> set_type;

bool input_exists(std::string input, set_type const & words) {
    return words.find(input) != words.end();
}

int main() {
    set_type words = {"abc", "bcd", "cde", "def", "efg"};
    std::string input;
    if (std::getline(std::cin, input)) {
        std::cout << "input: '" << input << "' ";
        if (input_exists(input, words))
            std::cout << "found\n";
        else
            std::cout << "not found\n";
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
$ g++ test.cc -std=c++11
$ echo "abc" | ./a.out
input: 'abc' found
$ echo "abcdefg" | ./a.out
input: 'abcdefg' not found
```

For reference:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal
- [Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1025391)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/find
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory